# In Laravel, why "should you only bind things into the service container and never attempt to register anything else..."

Tags: php, laravel, service-provider

I did see the SO warning that `The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed` when I posted this.

I continued posting it **because it is from an authoritative source**... which is the actual [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers#writing-service-providers).

I am asking **what** they mean and **what examples** can be given for  the warning that is given(see below).

I was reading the documentation on service providers and found the following:

> **Writing Service Providers**
>
> All service providers extend the Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider
>   class. Most service providers contain a  register and a boot method.
>   Within the register method, you should **only bind things into the
>   service container.** You should never attempt to register any event
>   listeners, routes, or any other piece of functionality within the
>   register method.

[Source is here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/providers#writing-service-providers)

No example is given and I do not quite get what they mean by that statement.

The answer may have been answered elsewhere, in which case I apologise as I didnt find it.

**What do they mean? Could you give an example of what not to do?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> After all of the providers have been registered, they are “booted”.

A common mistake when using service providers is attempting to use the services provided by another provider in the register method. Since, within the register method, we have no guarantee all other providers have been loaded, the service you are trying to use may not be available yet.

So, service provider code that uses other services should always live in the boot method. The register method should only be used for, you guessed it, registering services with the container. Within the boot method, you may do whatever you like: register event listeners, include a routes file, register filters.

Answer (score -1):

bind('servicName',function($app){
            return 'your code logic';
        })
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        app()->bind('servicName',
        function($app){
            return dd('your code logic');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to explain your answer.